# Pass arbitrary url as $_GET variable

Tags: php, url, query-string

Given some arbitrary url:

```
view.php?viewid=blahblahblah
```

Is there a way I can encode a query string which has the above URL as a variable and preserves it's (view.php's) query string?

Obviously, for some URL:

```
obvious.php?obvid=foobarzot&old_url=view.php?viewid=blahblahblah
```

will not work at all, but is there a php function with which I could encode view.php so that I could pass it around?

Cheers!

Comment: [`(raw)urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) the URL before adding it to the query string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode)